# Foreign key pointing to wrong identifier

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am having a peculiar problem when using association in Sequelize.

I have two models

**Rock**

```
rock_id         : { type: DataTypes.BIGINT, allowNull: false, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true },
rock_mode_id    : { type: DataTypes.BIGINT },
```

with associations:

```
associate: function(models) {
                    rock.hasOne(models.rock_mode, {foreignKey: "rock_mode_id"})
}
```

**Rock Mode**

```
rock_mode_id    : { type: DataTypes.BIGINT, allowNull: false, primaryKey: true },
rock_mode       : { type: DataTypes.STRING }
```

with assocations:

```
associate: function(models) {             
    rock_mode.belongsTo(models.rock, {foreignKey: "rock_mode_id", foreignKeyConstraint:false })
}
```

I am attempting to print out Rock with the RockMode but it is seeming to point to the wrong id

Here is the code for the render (in `rockString`):

```
db.rock
    .findAll({include: [db.rock_mode]})
    .success(
        function(rocks) {
            rockString += "<h2>Rocks</h2>"
            rocks.forEach(function(rock) {
                rock.getRockModeName(function(rockModeName){
                    rockString += JSON.stringify(rock)
                    callback(rockString);
                })

            })

    })
```

When I see the output:

```
{"rock_id":1,"rock_mode_id":1,"rock_mode":{"rock_mode_id":1,"rock_mode":"a"}}
{"rock_id":2,"rock_mode_id":1,"rock_mode":{"rock_mode_id":2,"rock_mode":"b"}}
{"rock_id":3,"rock_mode_id":1,"rock_mode":null}
{"rock_id":4,"rock_mode_id":1,"rock_mode":null}
{"rock_id":11,"rock_mode_id":1,"rock_mode":null}
```

It seems as if the the `"rock_mode_id"` of the `"rock_mode"` is referencing the `"rock_id"` instead of the `"rock_mode_id"`. Does anyone know why? Is there an issue with my `hasOne` or `belongsTo`? Or should I specify a `where` into the include?

EDIT:
EDIT:
it IS pointing to the wrong id, here is the resulting SQL

```
Executing (default): SELECT `rocks`.*, `rock_mode`.`rock_mode_id` AS `rock_mode.rock_mode_id`, `rock_mode`.`rock_mode` AS `rock_mode.rock_mode` FROM `rocks` LEFT OUTER JOIN `rock_modes` AS `rock_mode` ON `rocks`.`rock_id` = `rock_mode`.`rock_mode_id`;
```

Here's the problem:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN `rock_modes` AS `rock_mode` ON `rocks`.`rock_id`=`rock_mode`.`rock_mode_id`;
```

This should say

```
 ON `rocks`.`rock_mode_id`=`rock_mode`.`rock_mode_id`;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As answered on GitHub you need to invert your association.
For your schema Rock belongsTo RockMode, it does not have one, since the foreignKey is on Rock.